# Enable/disable task manager using win32 API function, not by windows registry

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-c++, taskmanager

Currently in windows application developed in C# I am disabling `Task manager` and `user switching option` by setting value of below registry:

Disable Task manager :

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System\\DisableTaskMgr` value `1`

Disable(Hide) user switching :

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System\\HideFastUserSwitching` value 1

But while testing this windows application on Windows 7 machine where logged in user in not in `Administrators` group faced issue of Access rights, here is the exception text:

> 12/16/2015 12:11:24 PM: Access to the registry key
>   'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System'
>   is denied. :Win32Error(0,0)

Later I checked manually adding subkey `DisableTaskMgr` through `regedit`, I get same message of `Access is Denied`.

In application manifest file I have enabled `requestedExecutionLevel` by setting : `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`. I also tried to run the application exe by `Run as Administrator`.

If I add that user in `Administrators` group then no issue is faced.

So, Is there any alternative to enable/disable task manger and hide user switching may be by using win32 API functions from `user32.dll`?
or any solution through `vc++`?

Business Requirement:

Well, It's an application of examination software where we want to restrict candidates to use any other application (web browser, file explorer, etc.) as well as killing this application while giving exam. so we have blocked task manager from start menu option as well as from ctrl+alt+del menu (screen), we also want to remove `switch user` option from ctrl+alt+del menu.

Comment: I hope that there isn't

Comment: @codroipo :(..no solution in vc++ even?

Comment: it is not possible because windows (regedit) is not allow to modify registry without administrator rights but if you want to solution with different scenario than let me know and explain your exact requirement.

Comment: @DarshanPatel, requirement is simple. I want to disable task manager and app switching, without taking care of admin rights (well I know this things need admin rights, which I already mentioned). I have tried registry solution but it wont work even if user has admin privileges but group policies are set to deny `Write` operation on registry.

Comment: @Amogh, swithching application means you want to disable alt+tab key

Comment: A hacky and ugly idea I have would be to disable some keys on the keyboard or automatically close TaskManager when it starts up. But I'm not very happy with this idea and with this suggestion :/

Comment: @Roman, I understand what you are saying and even I am agree with this but it's application in which we want to disable all this things so that, no buddy will kill the application or switch the user, but I really agree on what you say, it's really hacky and ugly idea

Comment: @Amogh Wait, is your goal to prevent your application from being killed, or is it to prevent other applications from being started? They're two entirely different things. For the former, what do you want to have happen when the user logs off? If the application needs to (effectively) continue running even then, implement it as a service, and just make a GUI to manage the service, without putting any business logic in the GUI. For the latter, Windows already comes with functionality that should more than cover your needs. One search term to use is "kiosk mode".

Comment: A useful question to ask yourself: “What’s to prevent a virus from doing the same thing?” https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040216-00/?p=40603/ - and btw, you will always need admin permissions to do what you want to do, because "Windows has decided to keep users in control of their own programs and data" (same source).

Comment: @hvd, I have explained my `Business Requirement:` in question which I have updated. Well about what if user logs off then it should be only the way (otherwise complete the exam without cheating) to kill the application (ugly idea) I know :)

Comment: @DirkVollmar, Yes sir but here ground situation is very different so that we have to take such actions to prevent cheating in exams. Anyways, I do respect of what you say `keep users in control of their own programs and data, and keep administrators in control of their own computer. `

Comment: So what you are looking for basically is a kiosk mode. Something like this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/12/17/step-by-step-enabling-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1-via-assigned-access.aspx - it is nothing you can do in your program run by the current user, it is something an administrator needs to configure. If you have questions about it I'd suggest you ask at either SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: @DirkVollmar, yes something like this, but if it's supporting only on windows 8.1 >. Then my bad luck may be because all (our client) we have are systems with windows 7..some other are having windows XP even :( but nice idea. Thanks!!

Comment: There is ways to do Koisk applications in XP and up. You just need to go and actually do some research.

Answer (score -1):

try using this application to disable taskmgr

[Ultimate Windows Tweaker v2.2 for Windows 7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista)

Comment: Thanks! but I cannot use third party app.